# Can a proper noun be used as adjective?

Tags: adjectives

I was reading [an editorial in 'The Hindu'](https://www.thehindu.com/opinion/editorial/a-difficult-campaign/article24392449.ece) and I came across a phrase in the headline:

> A difficult campaign: on the Pakistan elections

Is it correct? 'the Pakistan elections'. I don't know if a proper noun can be used as adjective.

For example, could I say:

> the India elections

in a headline?

Comment: This is an interesting question. It's obviously fine to use *India* here rather than *Indian*, but I can't place exactly why.

Comment: @Omegastick - RE: _It's obviously fine.... although I can't place exactly why._ Those are the best questions, aren't they? Now that we've tidied it up a bit, I wouldn't be surprised to see this get quite a few upvotes.

Comment: Yes, but they are not adjectives, since nouns and adjectives belong to different word classes (parts of speech). But proper nouns can be used as **modifiers**, for example "a United States warship"; "a Dell computer"; "a Beethoven symphony", "the United Kingdom elections. Your examples are fine too, though we would normally say "Indian elections", where "Indian" is an adjective.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use those nouns like that because they serve as attributive nouns. An attributive noun can serve as an adjective to the other noun following it.

Say, 'There is a bottle opener.' Now, 'bottle' there serves as an attributive noun which looks like an adjective at first glance.

Think of an even more complex phrase: Yorkshire football team captain!

All are nouns there!

Actually, it should be Yorkshire's football team's captain! But we don't write that. :)

Comment: "[The] Yorkshire football team's captain" only one apostrophe is needed. The football doesn't belong to Yorkshire, the team doesn't belong to football, so the proper  noun phrase is *Yorkshire football team* IOW The captain **of** the Yorkshire football team

Comment: @Mari-LouA okay, while I take that 'football' point, I stand by my words for Yorkshire. It's Yorkshire's team. The former part is edited. Thanks :)

Comment: It's "{det} Yorkshire team" or "Yorkshire's team".  With the apostrophe, "Yorkshire's" itself is a suitable determiner for its noun phrase and no other determiner is warranted.  Without it, some other determiner is required:  "the Yorkshire team", "a Yorkshire team", "yet another Yorkshire team", *et al*.