# Oxford Dictionary - Here "Oxford" is an adjective or noun?

Tags: grammar, nouns, modifiers, attributive-nouns

I like to know when noun is used as adjective.

Comment: It's not properly an adjective.  It's a noun acting attributively.  There are some answers here: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/210865/can-a-noun-be-used-to-describe-another-noun/210867#210867 ; https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/171959/can-a-proper-noun-be-used-as-adjective/171960#171960 ; https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/257675/a-word-poison-as-an-adjective/257700#257700

Answer (score 0):

Oxford is noun but here it is functioning as an adjective

Comment: Really? I thought it was always a noun.

Comment: Oxford is describing dictionary.Nouns can also function as an adjective.for more info about nouns functioning as an adjective you can use the following link https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/nouns-adjective.htm

Comment: If I say, Oxford University or Oxford University Pres?

Comment: Then, What is difference between compound noun and noun adjective?

Comment: Oxford University Pres is compound noun. Oxford is noun that's functioning as an adjective

Comment: "Oxford" is a noun in the proper name Oxford Dictionary, which we say has composite heads. Note that nouns don't function as adjectives -- they may function as subjects, objects, heads, modifiers and complements etc. Not everything that modifies a noun is an adjective!